# Plot bar chart with separate color legend - dash Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm trying to plot certain values using dash as a bar chart but use a separate column to map the colors. Using below, I'm plotting dates as a bar-chart that corresponds to a drop down bar.

Is it possible to keep the dates as the x-axis but use DOW (day of the week) as a discrete color map? I'll attach the current output below. The dates get plotted but there are a few issues.

1. The string formatting for each date in the dropdown isn't in date time
2. The color map isn't sequenced to the day of the week

   ```
   import dash
   from dash import dcc
   from dash import html
   from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
   import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
   import plotly.express as px
   import plotly.graph_objs as go
   import pandas as pd
   from datetime import datetime as dt

   df = pd.DataFrame({
          'Type': ['A','B','B','B','C','C','D','E','E','E','E','F','F','F'],
          })

   N = 30
   df = pd.concat([df] * N, ignore_index=True)

   df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.date_range(start='2022/01/01 07:30', end='2022/01/30 08:30', periods=len(df))
   df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], dayfirst = True).sort_values()

   df['DATE'], df['TIME'] = zip(*[(d.date(), d.time()) for d in df['TIMESTAMP']])
   df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

   df = df.sort_values(by = 'DATE')

   df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekday
   df = df.sort_values('DOW').reset_index(drop=True)
   df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.day_name()


   external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

   app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

   filter_box = html.Div(children=[

       html.Div(children=[
           html.Label('Day of the week:', style={'paddingTop': '2rem'}),
           dcc.Dropdown(
               id='DATE',
               options=[
                   {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['DATE'].unique()
               ],
               value=df['DATE'].unique(),
               multi=True
           ),

       ], className="four columns",
       style={'padding':'2rem', 'margin':'1rem'} )

   ])

   app.layout = dbc.Container([
       dbc.Row([
           dbc.Col(html.Div(filter_box, className="bg-secondary h-100"), width=2),
           dbc.Col([
               dbc.Row([
                   dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'date-bar-chart'), 
                       ),
               ]),
           ], width=5),
       ])
   ], fluid=True)


   @app.callback(
       Output('date-bar-chart', 'figure'),
       [Input("DATE", "value"),
       ])     

   def date_chart(date):

       dff = df[df['DATE'].isin(date)]
       count = dff['DATE'].value_counts()

       data = px.bar(x = count.index, 
                     y = count.values,
                     #color = dff['DOW'],
                     )

       layout = go.Layout(title = 'Date')
       fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout) 

       return fig


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8051)
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why do you want to use `DATE` as Dropdown but I think you should change it to string and then pass it to `dcc.Dropdown`. Used the previous way to add `color_discrete_map` I think you can revise your code as below:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

df = pd.DataFrame({
       'Type': ['A','B','B','B','C','C','D','E','E','E','E','F','F','F'],
       })

N = 30
df = pd.concat([df] * N, ignore_index=True)

df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.date_range(start='2022/01/01 07:30', end='2022/01/30 08:30', periods=len(df))
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], dayfirst = True).sort_values()

df['DATE'], df['TIME'] = zip(*[(d.date(), d.time()) for d in df['TIMESTAMP']])
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%Y-%m-%d')

df = df.sort_values(by = 'DATE')

df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekday
df = df.sort_values('DOW').reset_index(drop=True)
df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.day_name()
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].astype(str)
df['Color'] = df['DOW'].map(dict(zip(df['DOW'].unique(),
                    px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[:len(df['DOW'].unique())])))

Color = df['Color'].unique()
Category = df['DOW'].unique()

Color = df['Color'].unique()
Category = df['DOW'].unique()

cats = dict(zip(Category,Color)) 
external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filter_box = html.Div(children=[

    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Day of the week:', style={'paddingTop': '2rem'}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='DATE',
            options=[
                {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['DATE'].unique()
            ],
            value=df['DATE'].unique(),
            multi=True
        ),

    ], className="four columns",
    style={'padding':'2rem', 'margin':'1rem'} )

])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(filter_box, className="bg-secondary h-100"), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'date-bar-chart'), 
                    ),
            ]),
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)


@app.callback(
    Output('date-bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("DATE", "value"),
    ])     

def date_chart(date):
    if date:
        dff = df[df['DATE'].isin(date)]
        count = dff.groupby(['DATE',"DOW"])['DATE'].count().reset_index(name='counts')
        data = px.bar(x = count['DATE'], 
                  y = count['counts'],
                  color = count['DOW'],
                  color_discrete_map = cats,
                  )

        layout = go.Layout(title = 'Date')
        fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout) 

        return fig
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port = 8051)
```

I used groupby in `callback` to return new dataframe and then use it to make graph. Hope this help.

[image]